# How to log in with phone number using firebase with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I signed up with the phone number with OTP into firebase but after signed out, unable to log in with the same number. Does it need a password?
can I log in without a password or not?

Comment: hey check this project.it shows how log in with phone number and google .https://github.com/gildaswise/flutter_phone_auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basycally, when you sign out of the FirebaseUser, you need to resend the OTP code via SMS to log-in again using `.signInWithCredential`.